# SpringBoot application is running properly but the hibernate & MySql related properties are not working

Tags: mysql, hibernate, maven, intellij-idea, spring-boot

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = 
    "com.gmt.user",entityManagerFactoryRef = 
    "userEntityManager",transactionManagerRef = "userTransactionManager")

    public class UserConfig {


@Bean
@Primary
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean userEntityManager(){
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em= new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(userDatasource());
    em.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"com.gmt.user"});

    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

    HashMap<String,Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto","craete");
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect","org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql","true");
    em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
    return em;
}

@Bean
@Primary
public DataSource userDatasource(){
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schema_name");
    dataSource.setUsername("root");
    dataSource.setPassword("password12");
    return dataSource;

}

@Bean
@Primary
public PlatformTransactionManager userTransactionManager(){
    JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();

    jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(userEntityManager().getObject());

    return jpaTransactionManager;

}
```

}

Here is my SpringBoot Application

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.gmt")
    @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, 
    HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
    public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    SpringApplication.run(Client.class,args);

    System.out.println(" ***** Inside Spring Boot Application ***** ");


   }
   }
```

here is my pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>Simple_Spring</groupId>
<artifactId>Spring01</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>


<build>

    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And i have placed model class and respective repository in same folder.Application is running properly without any errors but not getting connected to database and not creating tables in the schema.Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Edited springboot application

Answer (score 1):

You have misspelled the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` property value here:

```
properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto","craete");
```

It has to be `create`, but you have it set to `craete`.

Comment: thank you for responding,i corrected it to "create", but its not working still.

Answer (score -1):

in your POM if you use **spring-boot-starter-data-jpa** no need to use the other artifacts of **`<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>`** . "**spring-boot-starter-data-jpa**" will bring in Hibernate as default JPA provider, this may cuase dependency conflicts I have seen similar issues because of that.
So you are saying no error displayed? did you debug?

Also in spring boot youc an set your properties as:

```
spring.datasource.*
```

spring boot JPA will ready it automatically

To change the hibernate properties we will use prefix

```
 `spring.jpa.properties.*`
```

with hibernate property name
On the basis of given data source URL, spring boot can automatically identify data source driver class. So we need not to configure driver class.

Edit 1 ________

```
#spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/concretepage
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait=20000
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=50
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-idle=20
spring.datasource.tomcat.min-idle=15

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings = false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql = true

logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

Comment: I removed "Spring-boot-starter-data-jpa" from pom.xml and i thought the Datasource and hibernate properties are not working because i explicitly excluded them in my main springboot application..i edited it.

Comment: Instead of hardcoding the mysql  and hiberante values i had put it in application.properties file but that still wont solve my problem.

Comment: This is the error i get if i exlude DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class & HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class       "Description:

Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE

Action:

If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).

"

Comment: Yep, just leaving "spring-boot-starter-data-jpa" but if you remove those classes in your properties file you must edit as (see my edit in my answer)

Comment: the properties must have that nomenclature, you tried that as well?